# Parse HTTP_USER_AGENT string in django.

Tags: django, http, user-agent

What is a best way to `parse` User Agent string from the `django request?`

```
request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '')
```

here is what i get in the string.

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36`

Not sure how to parse this information.

Is there any cost(time, + memory) efficient solution. 
I just need to parse the string thats' all.

Comment: Please explain, what information you need and why.

Comment: I have a user tracking middleware, and it saves HTTP_USER_AGENT info in the DB. i was wondring how to know what kind of browser my users are using most of the time?
that will require me to parse that `HTTP_USER_AGENT` string.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you can try this library :

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/user-agents/
```

**Example** :

```
from user_agents import parse

# iPhone's user agent string
ua_string = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3'
user_agent = parse(ua_string)

# Accessing user agent's browser attributes
user_agent.browser  # returns Browser(family=u'Mobile Safari', version=(5, 1), version_string='5.1')
user_agent.browser.family  # returns 'Mobile Safari'
user_agent.browser.version  # returns (5, 1)
user_agent.browser.version_string   # returns '5.1'

# Accessing user agent's operating system properties
user_agent.os  # returns OperatingSystem(family=u'iOS', version=(5, 1), version_string='5.1')
user_agent.os.family  # returns 'iOS'
user_agent.os.version  # returns (5, 1)
user_agent.os.version_string  # returns '5.1'

# Accessing user agent's device properties
user_agent.device  # returns Device(family='iPhone')
user_agent.device.family  # returns 'iPhone'
```

Comment: This is a middleware kind of stuff. so i was wondering how much efficient it is? as it will execute everytime with new request.

Comment: You can write your own parser using `regex` if you want predefined details. To make it efficient , u can store it in session . will remian in session until it gets expire . so if it found in session , no need to parse again .

Comment: Thats what i mean, can you see the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` string? `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36` I requested it from the Chrome, and it have all kind of broswer info, what technique to follow for parsing this?

Comment: Use this library. If your users are registered users, just save these information on login. If you need anonymous users, too, follow the advice to use session.