# Django detecting user browser - best way to do it

Tags: python, django, browser, agent

I have a django app, and I want to collect some info about the browsers of users logging in, like browser type, version, OS.  What will be the best way for doing so?  I thought of checking the header `request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, but how can I parse this string into info like IE9/Firefox, Windows/Linux etc?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374985/parse-http-user-agent-string-in-django

Comment: Also, consider using [`django_user_agents`](https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents).